# require existing control master for OpenSSH

Tags: ssh

I am looking for an option for OpenSSH on Linux to insist on using pre-existing control master connection. That is, I would like to make sure that that an ssh command fails if it cannot connect to the master connection socket and never tries to connect to the remote host itself.

I tried different combinations of ControlPath and ControlMaster, but it seems that ssh, when the master socket is not available, will try to connect in any case.

As a workaround I put in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Match host my-master-only-host   
  # Use non-existing port to insist on using master connection 
  Port 55555
```

so by default ssh fails and then switch to the real port when starting the master connection:

```
ssh -p 22 -M my-master-only-host
```

This works, but depending on firewall settings ssh without master may take a while until the connection timeouts. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess ProxyCommand can be used to enforce this. Have a look at socat for that purpose.

EDIT:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="socat - SOCKET:<path_to_control_path>" <hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggesion by tomek gave a hint how I can use ProxyCommand. The idea is to have in `.ssh/config`:

```
# By default prevent any connections via immediate exit from proxy.  
Match host my-master-only-host   
    ProxyCommand exit 1
```

Then I can call ssh when setting up the control master like:

```
ssh -M -o ProxyCommand=none my-master-only-host
```

Here `ProxyCommand=none` nullify the effect of the ProxyCommand setting in the config. This use of `none` is not documented, but works with at least OpenSSH 7.7.